# I can't install tensorflow on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am currently working on my Nvidia Jetson Nano 4GB following [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/06/getting-started-with-the-nvidia-jetson-nano/). I try to install tensorflow but a few moments later I have THAT 2500lines error: 'python version don't match your environment' . Okay, I want to see my actual version and I have a different answer for each request. What should I do?

[Python version screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuBm2.png)
[an error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DgUM.png)

Comment: That guide is 1.5 years old, that's ancient in Machine Learning terms. There's probably a lot of incompatibility issues if you try installing a current version of anything ML-related using a guide that old. https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html

Answer (score 0):

just write `python` in terminal to see your python version if that is what you are asking?